# Does Avro Schema Allow Conditional Fields?

Tags: java, json, avro, jsonschema, jackson-dataformat-avro

I'm planning to use Avro's `Java` API to build out a schema (preferably by using a tool which converts POJOs to `AVSC`).

1. Does Avro schema allow conditional fields like `JSON` schema does using `allOf`, `anyOf`, `dependencies` etc.?
2. If not, what's the best way to achieve conditional validation in Avro?
3. Alternatively, is there a tool to convert a `JSON` schema to `AVSC` (I already have a `JSON` schema defined with the conditional validation I need)?

**For example:**

- If `field1` is present, then `field2` should be present too.
- `field3` should always be present.
- If `field2` is present, then `field4` which is an `enum` of `[a,b,c]` can only have the value `[a,b]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent optional fields in Avro by making the field type a union between the actual type and null, e.g.:

```
{
    "name": "username",
    "type": [
      "null",
      "string"
    ],
    "default": null
},
```

> **1. Does Avro schema allow conditional fields like JSON schema does using allOf, anyOf, dependencies etc.?**

There is no way to make the schema for one field dependent on the value of another field.

> **2. If not, what's the best way to achieve conditional validation in Avro?**

Simply make the schema as retrictive as possible and then for any rules that you can't capture in the schema, simply apply them as part of a post-construction validation step.

E.g. taking your examples:

- If field1 is present, then field2 should be present too.

Simply make field1 and field2 optional, and apply the check on field2 during validation.

- If field2 is present, then field4 which is an enum of [a,b,c] can only have the value [a,b].

Again, simply apply the check on field4 during validation.

> **3. Alternatively, is there a tool to convert a JSON schema to AVSC (I already have a JSON schema defined with the conditional validation I need)?**

I doubt it. In any case, even if one did exist, given that Avro Schema is less powerful than JSON Schema, it woudn't solve your problem.